# Does the portal.azure.com Cloud Shell provide autocomplete for Powershell or Bash?

Tags: intellisense, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azureshell

Are there any keyboard shortcuts, configuration, browser extensions or other settings that can be set to provide intellisense for the Azure Cloud Shell on portal.azure.com?  An Edge or Chrome browser extension for either PS or Bash would suffice.

I am seeking any Intellisense or limited Predictive Intellisense or completers that can provide inline typing help for cli or powershell Shell commands in the browser Azure Shell outside the normal options of  --help  switch or PS  Get-Command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure CLI (Bash Cmdlets) has the Intellisense feature in Azure Cloud Shell when we run one command, i.e.,

`az interactive`

When you begin typing any `az` cmdlets, it will show you the next parameters to be passed to that command and can be completed by pressing `Tab` button.

[image: AzureCLIBashIntellisenseFeature]